# upgrading pdftk 1.41 to 1.44 how can I check for breaking changes?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, java, php

I have the wonderful task of finding out what ( if any ) breaking changes are if we upgrade from PDFTK 1.41 to 1.44

Here is our use-case

- We use PDFTK on the command line from a PHP application
- This is a legacy application running on PHP version 5.2.x
- We are migrating it to PHP 5.3

If anyone has any past experience on this, please share

Thanks

Also if someone could add the tag PDFTK

Comment: 1.44 or 1.4.4? Please correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the history file: https://github.com/onehub/pdftk/blob/master/changelog.txt
I guess this will only give you an idea, where to look more detailed. In fact you should re-verify the whole function.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, Thanks! Didn't know they moved to github